# url helpers not using host name in Capybara feature test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, actionviewhelper

In my spec I use AssetUrlHelper:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
```

so that I can test a page that should display an absolute URL to one of my files. I thought `asset_url` should do the trick:

```
asset_url(img.img_file(:medium))
```

Unfortunately while the spec runs this has no host name, e.g.

```
(byebug) asset_url("blurg.jpg")
"/images/blurg.jpg"
```

... not even if I specify the host name as an option:

```
(byebug) asset_url("blurg.jpg", host: "myhost.com")
"/images/blurg.jpg"
```

At the very least the second case is odd in that it contradicts this comment [in the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/606ce3f907cbccd9159bb558c0b57433b42f3975/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L151):

```
# If :host options is set, it overwrites global
# +config.action_controller.asset_host+ setting.
#
# ...
#
#   asset_url "application.js"                                 # => http://example.com/assets/application.js
#   asset_url "application.js", host: "http://cdn.example.com" # => http://cdn.example.com/assets/application.js
```

This has lead to a bug going unspotted until now. My test thinks there is no difference between the relative file path which my view outputs (wrongly) and the absolute url that should be there:

```
myhost.com/images/blurg.jpg #what I expect the test to check for
/images/blurg.jpg #what the test actually checks for
```

The contents of the view do not matter. I know how to fix it. I want to know for this case and for future reference, why does this helper not behave as I expect *in the test*, and how do I fix *the test*.

Answer (score 0):

A feature spec doesn't have the necessary Rails framework loaded in order to calculate the host. I'm a little surprised that providing the `:host` option doesn't work, but not hugely because there's a lot of smarts inside Rails concerning the URLs referring to the routing, resolving lots of things, and generally trying to be very smart.

If you switch over to a controller spec, then you'll find that the proper context is stubbed enough that `asset_url` works as advertised (without the `:host` option).